# FFMPEG not "decoding" the right url input

Tags: php, ffmpeg

Ok sorry everyone if the title is not very clear. Any idea would be helpful.

Basically I am trying to save small portions of videos and upload them to my server. The thing is, it seems that somehow the video input url I put is being redirected during the process, and FFmpeg get rid of some of it.

Explanation with a practical example:

```
ffmpeg -ss 5 -i "https://serverigetmyvideofrom.com/videos/xxxxx.mp4" -t 139 -y \
-codec:v libx264 -codec:a libfaac /var/www/vhosts/www/36.mp4 \
> /var/www/vhosts/xxx/block.txt 2>&1 &
```

And in the block.txt file, I have this error:

```
https://serverigetmyvideofrom.com/videos/x/xxxx/xx.mp4?someparameter%3D: Server returned 401 Unauthorized (authorization failed)
```

And so it seems that FFMPEG stopped the url at the caracter " : " but somehow I doubt it's the end of the url.

Nonetheless, I would like to know how I can access directly the end url?

Comment: This means you should somehow tell the server that is you, you haven't disclosed yet how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, use `curl` or `wget`?

```
curl 'https://serverigetmyvideofrom.com/videos/xxxxx.mp4' | ffmpeg -ss 5 -i - -t 139 -y \
-codec:v libx264 -codec:a libfaac /var/www/vhosts/www/36.mp4 \
> /var/www/vhosts/xxx/block.txt 2>&1 &
```

---

It looks like,
The server requires an authentication from the Client. Either **OAuth** or an **API** key.

Comment: What should I put as input of ffmpeg?

Comment: The data of the URL that CURL downloaded

Comment: so save on server then repass through ffmpeg? Could work but then couldn't automate it well i think

Comment: What server is it?